# How can I get a CSS3 border radius only on the top of my element?

Tags: css

Hi,
I'm using this code for a CSS3 Border Radius, how can I adapt it so that I only get a border radius on top?

```
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
```

The order is: top left, top right, bottom right and bottom left.

Answer (score 4):

Use the side specific border radius rules.

Ex:

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft:15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:15px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:15px;
border-top-left-radius:15px;
border-top-right-radius:15px;
```

Note that the most recent versions of both Chrome and Firefox support the border-radius rule without the prefix whis is needed only for older versions.

Comment: Always put unprefixed version last;

Answer (score 3):

Use the `border-radius` shorthand property:

```
border-radius:15px 15px 0 0; /* top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left */
```